# Do we have to share overnight train rooms in Europe?

Tags: trains, europe, transportation

My buddy and I are planning to take an overnight train. I notice on seat61 that the pictures of the rooms have up to 6 beds in them.

1. Does this mean we will be sleeping with other people or do we get the whole room to ourselves?
2. Is there some sort of rule that says if our party has a certain number of people (less than full capacity of the room) that we could get the whole room to ourselves?

Comment: Just FYI, the normal term for an 'overnight train room' is a 'sleeper cabin'.

Comment: Is booking a smaller cabin (eg 4 bed or 2 bed) where you'd fill all of it an option?

Comment: I assume you've checked that your particular train only has 6-bed cabins, but for future readers, plenty of trains in Europe have 2-bed sleepers, and some allow you to book them for yourself.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Unless you book the whole room (ie pay for all 6 beds), then yes, you may well be sharing with others.

Of course, depending on the time of the train, the service, and the route, and the time of year, it may not be full, and you may luck out and get the whole room to yourselves.

No, there's no 'partial occupancy claims full room' rule - if there's a spare bed, someone can buy that ticket and use it.  You could perhaps try asking new people to use a different room, warn them that you snore or something, but otherwise no.

Six is not so bad, try platzkart class in Russia where you have 54 beds in one big open carriage, or obshi class in Uzbekistan - no beds, and 100ish people just sitting for 24 hours(!).